# Control a sticky Slick Slider with vertical page scroll

Tags: slick.js

I have a slick slider implementation that is sticky at the bottom of a website. The slides are clickable and being used as an extra navigation element for a pillar page. Is there a way that I can modify which slide is active based on the vertical position of the page? As in, as I scroll down the page, I'd like the sticky slider to move horizontally and make the appropriate slide active based on page position. Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: are you looking for a horizontal scroll? so if you scroll down or up inside of the container that holds the images it moves to the right or left?

Comment: Yes the slider is a horizontal scroll and works. But I am trying to get that horizontal slider to move (it's not an auto slider) left and right based upon the position of the page. So as I scroll up or down on the page, the slider moves to show what is relevant to where I am on the page.